# Search within multiple values and perform some action

Tags: vba, excel

I have A column with data to search through. If value from column D does match let's say value from column A, then my script should take a relevant value from column B and copy it to a correct E cell. If D1 lets say matches A10 then take B10 and copy to E10, continue with D2. The code is:

```
Sub finddataalfa1()

Dim athletename As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

athletename = Sheets("db1").Range("D1").Value 'we search for a value in D1 cell 

finalrow = Sheets("db1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Finalrow
For i = 1 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 1) = athletename Then 'if match between lets say D1 and A1
    Cells(i, 5) = Cells(i, 2).Value 'copy B1 value to E1 cell
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This script works fine with a first value. It does it's job and finds a value from D1 cell in A column and copies relevant cell to E column and then stops.

I need it to take another value from D2 cell and do same again. (I need to loop I guess). Then D3, D4 etc. while D cell is empty.

Comment: removed, thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub finddataalfa1()

Dim athletename As String
Dim finalrow_A As Integer
Dim finalrow_D As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

finalrow_A = Sheets("db1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
finalrow_D = Sheets("db1").Cells(Rows.count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To finalrow_D
    athletename = Sheets("db1").Cells(i, 4).Value
    if athletename <> "Exclude This" then
        If Not Application.IsError(Application.VLookup(athletename, Range("A1:B" & finalrow_A), 2, False)) Then
            Range("D" & i).Offset(0, 1) = Application.VLookup(athletename,  _ 
            Range("A1:B" & finalrow_A), 2, False)
        End If
    End if

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If Intersect(Range("A1:A" & finalrow_A), Range("D" & i)) > 0 Then

RuntimeError: 91

Comment: @MichaelJ Sorry, Changed it.

Comment: this one works fine, but when it gets to a value in D column that cannot be found in A - it gives up an error and stops. is that possible to modify the code to make it get to a next value if the current is not in column A? thank you!

Comment: is that possible if athletename = "exclude this" go to next i
?
Thank You!

Comment: @MichaelJ you need to write and if that looks for the negative and then runs if it does not look.  I changed my code to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you compare the values in the same row number in each column, then you can make this code run with a small change. Put `athletename=Sheets.("db1").Range("D1").Value` inside the for loop like below. The value of "athletename" will be picked by next row with changing `i value`.

```
For i = 1 To finalrow
  athletename=Sheets.("db1").Range("D" & i).Value
  If Cells(i, 1) = athletename Then 'if match between lets say D1 and A1
  Cells(i, 5) = Cells(i, 2).Value 'copy B1 value to E1 cell
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: thank you for your help! but it is not always the same row :(
D1 can match A5, then B5 value has to be copied to E5

Answer (score 0):

You need a second loop to change the value of athletename as the next cell is checked. I'm assuming the max row is different for columns A and D, but it should still work if they're the same.

```
Sub finddataalfa1()

Dim athletename As String
Dim finalrow_A As Integer
Dim finalrow_D As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

finalrow_A = Sheets("db1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
finalrow_D = Sheets("db1").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To finalrow_D
    athletename = Sheets("db1").Cells(i, 4).Value

    For j = 1 To finalrow_A
        If Cells(j, 1) = athletename Then 'if match between lets say D1 and A1
            Cells(j, 5) = Cells(j, 2).Value 'copy B1 value to E1 cell
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

after some testing I realized that weird things are happening:

```
AB0023999   3999        AB0023999   3999
AB0024000   4000        AB0024000   4000
AB0024001   4001        AB0024001   4001
AB0024002   4002        5000000 
AB0024003   4003        AB0024003   4003
AB0024004   4000        AB0024004   4000
AB0024005   4005        AB0024005   4005
AB0024006   3999        AB0024006   3999
AB0023999   3999        56666       3999
AB0024000   4000        56666       4000
AB0024001   4001        56667       4001
AB0024002   4002        56668   
AB0024003   4003        56669       4003
AB0024004   4000        56670       4000
AB0024005   4005        56671       4005
AB0024006   3999        56672       3999
AB0023999   3999        56673       3999
AB0024000   4000        56674       4000
```

First lines are OK! D1 = A1 then it takes B1 and copies to E1 and so on. but when it gets to 56666 - it just brokes. I don't get why it puts 3999 to E cell!?

Comment: Can I ask why not use a simple vlookup?

Comment: I will have to remake script a bit later. A and B columns are in File1 and E column in file2 + they look messy